# Running specific check on the data key element

Tags: javascript

I have the following code working fine which checks for `null` and if a null is encountered, it stops checking and prints a console log.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "filename": "deletetestOne.js",
    "answer1": "Y",
    "answer2": null,
    "riskLevel1": null,
    "description": ""
  },
  {
    "filename": "deletetestThird.js",
    "answer1": null,
    "answer2": "Y",
    "riskLevel1": "1",
    "description": ""
  }
]

const isNull = (val) => val === null;
const hasNull = data.some(function (item) {
    return Object.values(item).some(isNull);
});
console.log(hasNull ? "Some of the values are null": "All good");
```

The above code has been just included to show how I'm checking for `null` values which is not related to what I'm looking for. My new data looks as shown below without any null values:

Now I have a slightly different data which doesn't contain `null` values any more:

```
const data = [
  {
    "filename": "deletetestOne.js",
    "answer1": "Y",
    "answer2": "N",
    "riskLevel1": "2",
    "description": ""
  },
  {
    "filename": "deletetestThird.js",
    "answer1": "N",
    "answer2": "N",
    "riskLevel1": "1",
    "description": ""
  }
]
```

And I want to run a specific check on the above data on `answer1` key element of the data. If it finds `Y` then it should stop checking else keep on printing values of `answer1`, which is probably going to be `N`.

**My Requirement:**

I want to check if `answer1` key element contains `Y` and if it does, then I want to break out of the loop and just print a console log saying `Found Y in answer1`. If it doesn't, then I can just print a console log saying `Didn't find Y in answer1`

Comment: It sounds like you need to replace `isNull` with a different function of your choice.

Comment: @CarlPatenaudePoulin I think OP needs to check specific key `answer1` for this variant

Comment: Yeah, I'm specifically looking to check `answer1` key for `Y`.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Please explain what you're actually after. `null`, `"N"`, when and why.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what the `isNull` function has to do with the rest of the question?  Also not entirely clear on the desired behavior; you want to print out the value of all `answer1` fields up until the first one that's "Y"?

Comment: @DanielBeck Please ignore `isNull` part. I added more clarification on my post.  I want to check if `answer1` key element contains `Y` and if it does, then I want to break out of the loop and just print a console log saying `Found Y in answer1`. If it doesn't, then I can just print a console log saying (`Didn't find `Y` in answer`)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I updated my post with more details. Please let me know if it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `.some()` and check for your `"answer1"` property value being `"Y"`

```js
const data1 = [{"answer1": "Y"}, {"answer1": "N"}];
const data2 = [{"answer1": "N"}, {"answer1": "N"}];

const someIsY = (arr) => arr.some(ob => ob.answer1 === "Y");

console.log(someIsY(data1)) // true
console.log(someIsY(data2)) // false
```

to get your specific "log" use:

```js
const report = someIsY(data1) ? "Found Y in answer1" : "Didn't find Y in answer1";
console.log(report);  // "Found Y in answer1"
```

to make your function more flexible in matching use:

```js
const data1 = [{"answer1": "Y"}, {"answer1": "N"}];
const data2 = [{"answer1": "N"}, {"answer1": "N"}];

const somePropVal = (arr, prop, val) => arr.some(ob => ob[prop] === val);

console.log(somePropVal(data1, "answer1", "Y")) // true
console.log(somePropVal(data2, "answer1", "Y")) // false
console.log(somePropVal(data2, "answer1", "N")) // true
```